# What do the h31 and h32 terms in a homography matrix mean?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-registration

I have used the MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY function in OpenCV (python3.6) to register a pair of images, and I am trying to interpret the 3 x 3 warp matrix the function returns:

```
H = 
[1.304     6.65e-2    -19.71
 3.19e-3   1.163      -22.92
 3.84e-5   2.06e-4    1     ]
```

I'm not sure what the h31 (`3.84e-5`) and h32 (`2.06e-4`) terms mean. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070411/what-do-the-elements-in-a-homography-matrix-mean), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429853/homography-estimation-result-an-affine-matrix?rq=1), and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), but all the examples show these terms as zero. In my mind:

- `1.304` is the stretching/scaling along *x*
- `6.65e-2` is the shearing in *x*
- `-19.71` is translation along *x*
- `3.19e-3` is the shearing in *y*
- `1.163` is the stretching/scaling in *y*
- `-22.92` is the translation along *y*

Is this right?

- `3.84e-5` is the stretching/scaling in *z*?
- `2.06e-4` is the shear in *z*?
- `1` is the translation along *z*?

I think *z* is the intensity of my image, and I guess I'm just trying to check that the terms in the last row are a transformation of intensity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: best to use version-*non*-specific tags. almost nobody monitors version-*specific* tags.

Comment: h31 and h32 is needed for perspective effect. If h31=h32=0, it becomes affine transform.

Comment: Very roughly speaking, they are for determining the denominator relative to the perspective effect based on the position on the original image.